# "U satisfies a maximum principle" - what might be meant with this statement?

Tags: maximum-principle

Suppose on a 2d lattice we have discretized some PDE and get something like
$$
U_{ij}^{n+1}=\mu(u_{i-1j}^n +u_{i j-1}^n+u_{i+1j}^n+u_{ij+1}^n)+(1-4\mu)u_{ij}^n
$$

What  then might be meant with a statement like
"$U_{ij}$ **satisfies a maximum principle**?"

And why might it be important that it satisfies a maximal principle?

Of course you can only guess but maybe this already helps me.

Comment: Presumably this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_principle .

Comment: Was my first thought, too. But sometimes "Maximum principle" also means something like that the solution is bounded from below and above?

Comment: In the context of PDEs, it's probably an analogue of the maximum principle for harmonic functions.

Comment: One reason for the importance of such a property that immediately comes into my mind is the easy identifiability of the malfunction/incorrect implementation of the numerical scheme. For example, given some boundary condition, if the numerical solution anywhere exceeds this then there is clearly something wrong with the numerical scheme.